# addProject is not a function (Sequelize)

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

In my app I've established an association between the `User` and `Project` table. using this code:

```
User.belongsToMany(Project, {
    through: "users_projects"
});
Project.belongsToMany(User, {
    through: "users_projects"
});
```

When I do a simple post request I get the following error:

***currentUser.addProject is not a function***

```
app.post("/project", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const project = await Project.findOrCreate({
            where: {
                name: req.body.name,
                content: req.body.content
            }
        });
        const currentUser = await User.findAll({
            where: { id: req.body.userId }
        });
        console.log(currentUser);

        await currentUser.addProject(project[0]);
        res.json(project[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findAll` returns an array, so your code should be

```
await currentUser[0].addProject(project[0])
```

However, if you are querying with `id`, you can use `findByPk` to get object.

```
const currentUser = await User.findByPk(req.body.userId);
await currentUser.addProject(project[0])
```

Comment: Alternatively, `findOne` can be used in place of `findAll` in the original code if id is not the primary key, which would be unlikely, but if the search was by email for example.